# I need help pertaining to binary files

Tags: java, binaryfiles

When I use `writeByte(346);` to a binary file and then do `readByte();` it returns 90, not 346. I'm perplexed and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: what makes you think 346 fits a byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

346 doesn't fit in a single byte.

So 346 overflows and you get 346 - 256 (2^8) = 90.

You need at least 2 bytes to store 346.

---

`writeByte(int)` takes a `signed int` as parameter, so the limits for one byte are -128 to 127

Comment: Wow, duh. Thank you so much.

Comment: I just tried it again, I wrote 181 and read it in as -75. It seems as though if you write a number above 128 it will start writing in the negatives. Weird.

Comment: @RaudKelly See my updated answer. It also depends on how the function writes the values (I don't know for Java). In some cases you could end up with only the lower or higher byte of a 16 bit signed integer for example. Anyway, you have to make sure the values don't overflow.